# Unable to download Maven dependency - AnypointStudio

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I am running into an issue where I am unable to download dependencies properly for my Mulesoft project. I have successfully installed everything from my home PC, but my work PC seems to be struggling.

Things I have tried:

1. mvn clean install
2. mvn clean install -U
3. mvn compile
4. Everything that is involved with setting 'Anypoint Studio (Mulesoft Eclipse IDE)' up to use Maven and the appropriate JDK.
5. I have tried creating truststore and adding the appropriate certificates to the repositories - I have also made sure to configure the AnypointStudio.ini file to point to this truststore.
6. Deleting .m2 folder, also tried deleting the files specifically.
7. I am able to access the repositories directly through the browser.

This is the error I am getting, I feel like it is seperate from AnypointStudio and strictly has to do with Maven.

> Downloading from mulesoft-release:
>   http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-app-maven-plugin/1.2/mule-app-maven-plugin-1.2.pom
>   Downloading from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-app-maven-plugin/1.2/mule-app-maven-plugin-1.2.pom
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the
>   POMs: [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
>   org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.2 @ [ERROR]
>   Unknown packaging: mule @ line 9, column 16

I am finding that when I try to install any of these dependancies I end up with files that are appended with .lastUpdated.

**I am just looking for more ideas on how I can resolve this, does anyone have an idea?**

mvn clean install -X

```
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-app-maven-plugin/1.2/mule- app-maven-plugin-1.2.pom [DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\scuvan\.m2\repository\org\mule\tools\maven\mule-app-maven-plugin\1.2\mule-ap p-maven-plugin-1.2.pom.lastUpdated [DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging mule from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependen  cies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1                       .2 @ [ERROR] Unknown packaging: mule @ line 9, column 16  @ [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependen                                      cies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1                       .2 @ [ERROR] Unknown packaging: mule @ line 9, column 16

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:383)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) [ERROR] [ERROR]   The project com.mycompany:salesforce-netsuite-integration:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\scuvan\Dev\AnypointStudio\                                   salesforce-netsuite-integration\pom.xml) has 2 errors [ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its depe      ndencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:j                           ar:1.2: Could not transfer artifact org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:pom:1.2 from/to mulesoft-release (ht                                      tp://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.                                      security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target                          
-> [Help 2] org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its           dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plu                            gin:jar:1.2
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupExtensionsRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.j                                      ava:848)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.createProjectRealm (DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:                                    197)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultModelBuildingListener.buildExtensionsAssembled (DefaultModelBuildingListener                                      .java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingEventCatapult$1.fire (ModelBuildingEventCatapult.java:44)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.fireEvent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1350)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:444)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:424)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:583)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2                         or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule                     
-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.2
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal (DefaultPluginDependencie                                      sResolver.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolve                                      r.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.resolveExtensionArtifacts (DefaultMavenPluginMana                                      ger.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupExtensionsRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.j                                      ava:841)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.createProjectRealm (DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:                                    197)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultModelBuildingListener.buildExtensionsAssembled (DefaultModelBuildingListener                                      .java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingEventCatapult$1.fire (ModelBuildingEventCatapult.java:44)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.fireEvent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1350)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:444)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:424)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:583)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>salesforce-netsuite-integration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule salesforce-netsuite-integration Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.5.0</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>  
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Run maven with `-X` or `--debug`, to obtain more information about the problem.

Comment: I added the -X and posted the result.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If you provided the pom.xml it would me easier to find a solution

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezSoria I added it if you want to take a look.

Comment: Is 3.5.0 mule version mandatory for you to use?

Answer (score 0):

The root error is visible if you scroll to the right of the last exception:

`PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

This is probably caused by some network proxy or firewall. You can try changing the protocol for the Mule repository to https (eg: https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/) as that avoids a protocol redirection that confuses some proxies. If that fails you'll probably have to ask your network administrators to whitelist the URL for the repository.